# What Runnable to Pass when adding a listener to ApiFuture<WriteResult> and ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot>?

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am saving a document to Google Cloud Firestore using Google Cloud Functions in Java language.

```
    DocumentReference userDoc = firestore.document("Users/user1");
    final Map<String,Object> UserData = new HashMap<String,Object>(){{
      put("Name", "First Last");
    }};
    ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = userDoc.set(UserData);
```

I want to add a listener to `future` here.

```
    future.addListener(/* which Runnable listener to pass here to 
                      process the WriteResult object 
                      when the future completes? */, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

I am unable to find a Runnable which can serve the purpose here. I know I can call `future.get()` method to hold the execution and get the WriteResult object but I don't want to do that.

Also, unable to understand how to add a listener to `userDoc.get()`.

**I have searched StackOverflow and Github already. Could not find anything helpful.**

All the posts talk about `ApiFuture.addListener()` which is deprecated and is not available now.

Please find below my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>some.group.Id</groupId>
  <artifactId>cloud-functions</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.functions/functions-framework-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
      <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-auth -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-auth -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
      <version>8.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>1.114.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>function-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <functionTarget>com.infonotics.stocklyticsusa.FirstFunction</functionTarget>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Already wasted 2 days. Please help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can use `ApiFutures.addCallBack`:

```
static <V> void     addCallback(ApiFuture<V> future, ApiFutureCallback<? super V> callback, Executor executor)
```

https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.9.1/apidocs/

Example:

```
    ApiFuture<WriteResult> result1 = 

    ApiFutures.addCallback(result1, new ApiFutureCallback<WriteResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(WriteResult writeResult) {

        }
    }, Runnable::run);
```